# What do you do with questions that just got solved?

Tags: discussion, questions, self-answer

What is one supposed to do with question that just go solved, as in not because the answers or your own effort on it helped remove it. But something like you asked the question while having the problem, got back from lunch and the problem is no more. Or as in [this](https://superuser.com/q/693210/213198) case you just restarted your application and the problem it no more there.

Should it be deleted and be left as it is?

Comment: If it is not reproducible, I see no advantage in keeping it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If the issue was solved by something you did (install a missing dependency, add something to the path etc...), post that as an answer.

If it was something unknown (a reboot helped, but you don't know why it helped), deleting the question is best, as there is no way to mark a correct answer that will be *helpful* to others.

If the issue is persistent - that is, repeats, the question may do more good by staying even with the answer of "a reboot helps, but I don't know why". This gives others a chance to reproduce or try to find a different way to solve the issue.

Comment: "I've restarted the computer and the problem went away" can still be useful to others, even if you don't know why it helped. Can it not?

Comment: @JanDvorak - possibly. But that goes into black magic / cargo cult mindset, in my opinion. I'd rather know that a file lock didn't get released which is why a reboot helped. For a transient issue (not reproducable), I'd rather not see a question.